# Is it possible to define $S_n$ with a transposition series?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group, and $e\in S_n$ the identity permutation. Let $\pi_i\in S_n$ be transpositions in the group.
Define a transposition series as a composition of transpositions:
$$\overset{n!}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcirc}}\pi_i=\pi_{n!}\circ...\circ \pi_1=e$$
And define its partial transposition series $\sigma:\mathbb{N}_{<n!}/\{0\}\rightarrow S_n$ as:
$$\sigma(k)=\overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcirc}}\pi_i=\pi_{k}\circ...\circ\pi_1$$
Where $k\in \mathbb{N}_{<n!}/\{0\}$.

My question is:
Is it possible to prove that there exists a transposition series for each nontrivial $S_n$ such that its partial transposition series $\sigma$ is injective?

### Considerations

The first three symmetric groups, $S_n$, for $n=1,2,3$ are trivial:

For $n=1$ the group is trivial.

For $n=2$, we define the complete series as:
$$\overset{2}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcirc}}\pi_i=\tau\circ \tau=e$$
Where $\tau=\begin{pmatrix}1 &2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$.
Its partial series only has one element, so it must be injective.

For $n=3$ we need to define the following transpositions:
$$\rho_1=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&3\\1&2&3\end{pmatrix}, \rho_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\1&3&2\end{pmatrix},\rho_3=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\3&2&1\end{pmatrix}$$
It is then straightforward to check that the complete transposition series:
$$\overset{6}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcirc}}\pi_i=\overset{6}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcirc}}\rho_i=e$$
Has an injective partial series if we let $\rho_4=\rho_1$. (Alternatively, the index $i$ can be let to run twice mod 3 in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}}$ for $\rho_{i+1}$).

I'm still working on the 4th case, and i suspect induction can be used to construct a proof for the general case, $S_n$. My conjecture is that an injective partial series $\sigma$ exists for every $S_n$, but the complete one might not; i.e., $\nexists \pi \in S_n$:
$$\pi\circ\overset{n!-1}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcirc}}\pi_i=e$$
Got any ideas?

Comment: Why are there $n!+1$ elements?

Comment: I just think it is important to find out if the series can end where it started. Also, it made the problem easier to state... Still, i might rephrase it later. Feel free to work it out on your own terms.

Comment: Aren’t there $\binom n2$ transpositions? And the identity is not one. I have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: I didn't know that the identity wasn't regarded as a transposition. Thanks for pointing it out: its probably the cause of the lurking $+1$ in the equations. The easy way to understand the statement of the problem is via a sequence of transpositions that *pass* through every element of $S_n$, only once,  when composed one after the other.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then it seems to be the same as asking whether there is a Hamiltonian path (or cycle) in the Cayley graph for the symmetric group with the transpositions as generators.

Comment: Yes! It's basically a path through the symmetric group, with every "step" of the path being a transposition.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279844/gray-code-of-all-permutations . 
Section (I guess it's really subsubsection) 7.2.1.2 in Donald Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*, volume 4A surveys this and many similar problems. Algorithm P is one possible answer to your question.